# Mongoose get nested document using another field

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nested

Assume that I have a document inside a collection

```
{
  _id: "3434v4vcvc254t34vtds",
  currentItemId: "v281",
  items: {
      v279: [/*Some Data*/],
      v280: [/*Some Data*/],
      v281: [/*Some Data*/]
  }
}
```

I need to fetch current item.
However I can do it with using two query

```
let data= await schema.findById("3434v4vcvc254t34vtds", {currentItemId});
let itemId = `items.${data.currentItemId}`
let item = await schema.findByID("3434v4vcvc254t34vtds", { [itemId] })
```

**I need to fetch current item using one query.**

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @J.F. expected output: v281 array inside the items document

Answer (score 0):

Use `populate` after `findById`.

```
const data = await schema.findById('3434v4vcvc254t34vtds').populate('currentItemId').exec()
```